# Print the contents of a linked list after adding an item to the list

Tags: java, linked-list

How to print the contents of a linked list after adding an item to the list?

I have coded the linked list in which I try to add a value in the middle of the list.
I have to see the content of the linked list after adding.

How can I do this ?

Here is the code:

```
public class LinkedList {
    int item;
    LinkedList next;

    public LinkedList()  // null constructor 
    { }

    // constructor to add pass the item and next value
    public LinkedList(int item,LinkedList next) 
    {
        this.item= item;
        this.next= next;
    }

    // constructor for items with null reference ie. the last element
    public LinkedList(int item) 
    {
        this(item,null);
    }

    // inserting an item in the linkedlist
    // (this assigns old reference to the new items next)
    public void additem(int item) 
    {
        this.next = new LinkedList(item,next);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        LinkedList l1 = new LinkedList();
        LinkedList l2 = new LinkedList();
        LinkedList l3 = new LinkedList();
        LinkedList l4 = new LinkedList();
        l1.item = 3;
        l1.next = l2;
        l2.item = 5;
        l2.next = l3;   
        l3.item = 7;
        l3.next = l4;
        l4.item = 9;
        l4.next = null;

        System.out.println(l1);

        // inserting an item after l1 (so l1 points to the newly added value 
        // and the new one gets the nxt items refernce)
        l1.additem(8);
    }
}
```

Maybe there will be some mistakes in the code. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: So what's the question? Are you getting an exception? Is the code not behaving as expected?

Comment: its working fine but i need to know the contents of the linked list that is both the item and the next address after an item is inserted.

Comment: This is odd.  The question actually contains 2 questions, someone asks "What is the question?" and you reply with something that is ..not a question!

Comment: @AndrewThompson I did not checked that before i submitted mine...
I apologise.

Comment: @user2802582  do you want to print the contents of the linked list?

Comment: Override `toString()` on your class to produce what kind of output you want to see. The method it inherits from `Object` only returns the class name and hash code.

Comment: @Lakshmi yes i need to know the contents of the linked list..

Comment: Without using a do while loop can't it be done by `public static void traverse( ListNode list){
    
 while(list.next!=null){
  System.out.println(list.item);
  list=list.next;
 
 }
 System.out.println(list.item);

}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See you need to change your additem class and define a traverse method .

The add item method you need to pass the old node after which the new node is to be inserted and return the old node and reassign it.

The traverse method you have to manually traverse from one element to another .

```
public static LinkedList additem(LinkedList l1,int item) //inserting an item in the linkedlist (this assigns old reference to the new items next)
{
LinkedList l2=new LinkedList(item,l1.next);
l1.next = l2;
return l1;

}

public static void traverse( LinkedList l1){
    do{
        System.out.println(l1.item);
        if(l1.next!=null){
            l1=l1.next;
        }
    }while(l1.next!=null);
     System.out.println(l1.item);
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    LinkedList l1 = new LinkedList();
    LinkedList l2 = new LinkedList();
    LinkedList l3 = new LinkedList();
    LinkedList l4 = new LinkedList();
    l1.item = 3;
    l1.next = l2;
    l2.item = 5;
    l2.next = l3;   
    l3.item = 7;
    l3.next = l4;
    l4.item = 9;
    l4.next = null;

    //traverse(l1);

    l1=additem(l1,8); // inserting an item after l1 (so l1 points to the newly added value and the new one gets the nxt items refernce)
     traverse(l1);
}
```

**output :**
3
8
5
7
9

Comment: @user2802582  checked this solution?

Comment: Thanks,I can get the result even without editing the additem() method using traverse method you gave. There i was assigning the old next item reference to the newly created object.

Comment: @user2802582 Glad that you got it...accept the answer if it was useful to you,as it might help others landing in this question Thank you.

Comment: Without using a do while loop can't it be done by [code] public static void traverse( ListNode list){while(list.next!=null){
  System.out.println(list.item);
  list=list.next;
 
 }
 System.out.println(list.item);[\code]

Answer (score 0):

I think your additem method is not correct.Here you are unable to insert the item. Check the syntax here.

```
public void additem(int item) 
{
Linkedlist node = new Linkedlist(item);
node.next = this.next;
this.next =node;

}
```

Read this:- http://www.softwareandfinance.com/Java/Singly_Linked_List.html

Comment: For that i am passing the old reference as next to the newly created object. {this.next =new LinkedList(a,next);}  so the new object will be updated with the old objects reference(the one before which the node is to be inserted ).